# javascript - how to get ID of clicked document from query list (from Firestore)?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, onclick

I want to achieve a clickable Firestore list like in this [Onclick interface video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WR4QAiVuCw), but I am not able to with javascript for web. This is what I tried:

Here is a query example from https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data.

```
db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true)
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        var id = doc.data().id;
        var templ = "";
        templ = 
        "Id: "+id+"<br>";
        document.getElementById("cities-list").innerHTML += templ;  
    });
})
```

I display the query in the div ok but how can I append a button or clickable div like the button onclick part to each line with which I would get the id of clicked item and write this id into the div like this  `document.getElementById("result-list").innerHTML = doc.id`? Button part like this gives me error of wrong element closure.

```
templ = 
"Id: "+id+"<br>"+
"<button onclick='getElementById('cityDetail').innerHTML="+ id +"'>Set clicked city</button><br>";
document.getElementById("cities-list").innerHTML += templ;
```

I am a begginer, thank you for any tip.

Comment: What exactly does `doc.data()` do? You have to save the value of doc for each element if you want to access after looping through them.

Comment: doc.data().id for example gives me the id of document and I want to append button with which I write this id value into another particular div. Please what do you mean to save the values?

Comment: You should create a DOM Element for each Button. Then persist the wanted value as an HTML data attribute. This way you still only need one query. Proceed adding an onclick event listener to trigger your action, providing its own data attribute.

Comment: I tried, but I am not able to create a DOM well so I could use value as HTML with this added line "<button onclick='getElementById('cityDetail').innerHTML="+name+"'>Set userName</button>"+"<br>". So how can I create it please? It writes me I have wrong element closure after this part "onclick='getElementById(".

Answer (score 3):

```
db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true)
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        var uid = doc.data().uid;
        var name = doc.data().name;
        var templ = "";
        templ = 
        `'Uid:' ${uid} '<br>'
        `'Name:' ${name} '<br>'`;
        document.getElementById("cities-list").innerHTML += templ;  
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

Comment: The first code works well, but I would like to add a button to each line to work something like this: <button onclick='getElementById('cityDetail').innerHTML="+name+"'>Set userName</button>